# MySQL Workbench - default datatype sizes

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, varchar

In MySQL Workbench, is there a way to set the default datatype sizes?

For example, whenever I select the VARCHAR datatype, it defaults to VARCHAR(45).

In most cases, I set the length to VARCHAR(255).

So, to save myself some extra effort, how would I set the default to VARCHAR(255)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In version 5.2.47:

File > Properties > "Model" tab. In the "Column defaults" section for the "column type" field, change the value to VARCHAR(255).

Comment: For version 6.0 this has been moved slightly:

Edit > Preferences > Model > Column Type

Comment: In version 6.3 it's: Edit > Preferences > Modeling > Defaults > Column Type

Comment: In version 8.0: MySQLWorkbench > Preferences > Modeling > Defaults > Column Type